# select and order date from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have date in database in this format 04-03-12 23:00:00. How I can convert it to this format  16.02.2012  and still user order by ? Because when I used to_char then order by doesnt work correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dates are not stored with any for at - at least if you are using a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` format, which you really should be. You can just use the raw column in the `order by`, something like:

```
select to_char(date_field, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
from my_table
order by date_field;
```

If you have it stored as a `VARCHAR`, which I can't stress enough would be a bad thing, you'd have to convert to a date for the `order by` and to a `DATE` and back to a `VARCHAR`, something like:

```
select to_char(to_date(varchar_field, 'DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
from my_table
order by to_date(varchar_field, 'DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```